# Renewcommand \textspanish

Tags: macros, pdftex, babel

Let's say I write a LaTeX document that usually is compiled with xelatex (and polyglossia), but I'd like to have pdflatex (and babel) as a fallback (when I send it to someone who might not have xelatex installed). For this I'd write `\textspanish{}` in the document and I came up with the following redefinition (wrapped basically in `if pdflatex`):

```
\newcommand{\textspanish}[2][]{\foreignlanguage{spanish}{#2}}
```

This approach seems to work fine for most languages, but for some reason babel has already a `\textspanish` command defined. So I tried the same with `\renewcommand` but this went into infinite recursion or something (`TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]`) for a reason I don't understand.

Sample document (works with xelatex, fails with pdflatex):

```
\documentclass[english,]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[shorthands=off,spanish,english]{babel}
  \newcommand{\textspanish}[2][]{\foreignlanguage{spanish}{#2}}
\else
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage[]{english}
  \setotherlanguage[]{spanish}
\fi
\begin{document}

Hello \textspanish{Hola}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Polyglossia already defines `\textspanish`, which exactly does the same as you want to obtain.

Comment: huh, but I cannot use Polyglossia with pdflatex, right? (see first sentence of my question..)

Comment: Of course not, but having an example would be better.

Comment: No, an example of a simple document and what you mean by “fallback”.

Comment: That is quite complicated to test for the engine.

Comment: Every TeX distribution should have XeTeX available by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution not requiring another package:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex\
  \usepackage[shorthands=off,spanish,main=english]{babel}
  \let\oritextspanish\textspanish
  \AddBabelHook{spanish}{beforeextras}
    {\renewcommand{\textspanish}{\oritextspanish}}
  \AddBabelHook{spanish}{afterextras}
    {\renewcommand{\textspanish}[2][]{\foreignlanguage{spanish}{##2}}}
\else
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage[]{english}
  \setotherlanguage[]{spanish}
\fi
\begin{document}

Hello \textspanish{Hola n\sptext{os}}

\end{document}
```

An issue related to the main language is also fixed (and I wonder if `[2][]` is intended, because the optional argument is not used at all).

Comment: Thanks, that looks even better! The `[2][]` is due to polyglossia's `\textenglish[variant=british]` syntax...

Comment: "main language has been fixed": you mean changing `\usepackage[spanish,english]{babel}` to `\usepackage[spanish,main=english]{babel}`? What's the difference?

Comment: @mb21 The behavior is not well defined when a language is set as global and as package option. With the key `main=` we make sure which the main language is (look at the log file when this key is no used).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by “fallback”. The problem seems to be that with `polyglossia` a `\textspanish` command already exists as soon as you enable Spanish; the good news is that this command essentially does `\foreignlanguage{spanish}`.

The bad news is that `babel-spanish` defines `\textspanish` (I don't know why they chose this name) and there's essentially *no* hope of using it as you'd like.

Here's an example of how `\textspanish` is used in `spanish.ldf`, that also hints at what it does, that is, it does some setup:

```
203 \def\extrasspanish{%
204   \textspanish
205   \mathspanish
206   \ifx\shorthandsspanish\@empty
207     \expandafter\spanishdeactivate\expandafter{\es@shlist}%
208     \languageshorthands{none}%
209   \else
210     \shorthandsspanish
211   \fi}
```

The definition of `\textspanish` is made step by step, so it's not readily available. My opinion is that this should be an internal command (so with a different name), because it does nothing really useful at the user level (and it's not documented, by the way). But it would be quite complicated (and not portable across documents without also copying the patches), changing `spanish.ldf` macros so that they use a different name.

Conversely, `polyglossia` uses a consistent interface: for every language `<language>` loaded, one has `\text<language>` that's an abbreviation for `\foreignlanguage{<language>}` plus some adaptations for it doing the right thing also in context of right-to-left languages.

Comment: Thanks, but I get `Command \textspanish already defined. Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.` with `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014)`. Does this really work with your pdfTex (which version)?

Comment: @mb21 I don't get the error.

Comment: I tried with `pdflatex` in TeX Live 2013, 2014 and 2015 and there's no `\textspanish` command defined if loading `babel`. Of course you have a wrong setting of `babel`, having language options both local and global.

Comment: Really? That's odd. Actually my version is MacTeX-2014, so maybe that makes a difference. But this [Babel 2009 manual](http://www.pvv.ntnu.no/~berland/latex/docs/babel.pdf) even mentions `\textspanish`..?

Comment: @mb21 Very curious. I'm investigating. Anyway, there's little hope of being able to use `\textspanish` as you want.

Comment: @egreg But it *is* documented. See page 16 (TL2015).

Comment: @JavierBezos The *existence* is mentioned. What the command does isn't.

Comment: @egreg Please, read the whole manual. Page 3 explains features are split into several groups -- captions, date, text, math y shorthands, the last 3 corresponding to extras. It also explains (p. 10s) the commands belonging to the text group, and finally p. 16 says how to cancel those groups (see also p. 21).

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that `\textspanish` is used in the language switching commands. so  you can try something like this:

```
\documentclass[english,]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex,xpatch}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex\
  \usepackage[shorthands=off,spanish,english]{babel}
  \let\oritextspanish\textspanish
  \patchcmd\extrasspanish{\textspanish}{\oritextspanish}{}{}
  \patchcmd\noextrasspanish{\textspanish}{\oritextspanish}{}{}
  \renewcommand{\textspanish}[2][]{\foreignlanguage{spanish}{#2}}
\else
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage[]{english}
  \setotherlanguage[]{spanish}
\fi
\begin{document}

Hello \textspanish{Hola}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, works nicely thanks! Do I read this correctly that you are 1) saving the original `\textspanish` as `\oritextspanish` 2) path the babel-spanish commands to use `\oritextspanish` instead of `\textspanish`?

Comment: Yes, but be aware that I didn't made really thorough tests. Also I agree with egreg that the name in babel-spanish is not good. You should inform the author.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer There are so many unfortunate macro names out there... This name backs to 1997 and for almost 20 years there has been very little trouble with it. I think it's too late to change it, and with the new babel I'm working on many of those pitfalls will vanish (hopefully).

Comment: There is also `\notextspanish` to keep in mind. And this is what I called "non portable": you can't fetch some text to another document without also adding the patches in the preamble.

Comment: @egreg `\notextspanish` is simply defined as `\bbl@nonfrenchspacing`, so it shouldn't be affected by a redefinition of `\textspanish`. Also you always need preamble commands (definitions, \usepackage, tikz libraries, ...)  before you can compile a snippet -- that's why we request complet document so often -- so I don't see why a few lines more line in the preamble suddenly count as "non portable".

Comment: @JavierBezos You could change all `\textspanish` in `spanish.ldf` into `\bbl@textspanish` and add, at the end `\let\textspanish\bbl@textspanish` conditionally to an appropriate option not having been given. So a user could disable `\textspanish` being defined and use it. Of course this is also not fully portable, but just requires setting an option and not a full set of patches.